# Template that accepts 2 numeric values

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to templates in C++ and i attempted to make one with two numeric values:

```
template <
    typename T, typename T2,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T2>::value, T2>::type>
T distance(vertex<T2>& p_Vertex1, vertex<T2>& p_Vertex2) {
  return sqrt(pow((p_Vertex2.x - p_Vertex1.x), 2) +
              pow((p_Vertex2.y - p_Vertex1.y), 2));
}
```

Errors:

```
1> C: \ Users \ User \ Desktop \ Library \ src \ vertex.cpp (4): warning C4348: 'distance': redefinition of the default parameter. Parameter 3.
1> C: \ Users \ User \ Desktop \ Library \ include \ Utils \ vertex.h (30): message: see the declaration of 'distance'
1> C: \ Users \ User \ Desktop \ Library \ src \ vertex.cpp (4): warning C4348: 'distance': redefinition of the default parameter. Parameter 4.
1> C: \ Users \ User \ Desktop \ Library \ include \ Utils \ vertex.h (30): message: see the declaration of 'distance'
```

this function is declared in vertex.h and defined in vertex.cpp; vertex is a template class that accepts a numeric value.

How am i using it:

```
    vertex<double> v1(9.34342342, 5.34);
    vertex<double> v2(69.67, 5.45);

    float dist = distance<float, double>(v1, v2);
    std::cout << "Distance: " << dist << std::endl;
```

#### Solved:

I solved moving the template function the same header file.

Comment: "I am new to templates in C++" - then you should probably wait a few months/years before you dive into something like `template<typename T, typename T2, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, 
T>::type, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T2>::value, T2>::type>
T distance(vertex<T2>& p_Vertex1, vertex<T2>& p_Vertex2)`..

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` in your code? Then your function perhaps collide with [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)? Also see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. And copy-paste the full and complete build output of that example so we can see the full error output.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to copy-and-paste the error message into your question. Typing the error message might inadvertently change something. (For example, it is unlikely that your compiler used the non-word "ridefinition" in the error message.)

Comment: no i don't have using namespace std; in my code

Comment: Not the direct cause of your current problem but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Please share a complete example, including the call to this template that fails. This seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/ZhbX39) for me.

Comment: As the error message tells you you define the default parameter in the declaration **and** in the definition. When you have separate declaration and definition put the default parameter value in the declaration only. That being said with you need to implement the templates in the header.

Comment: "*this function is declared in vertex.h and defined in vertex.cpp*" - [that doesn't work for templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/), only for non-templates.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I completely disagree. Why wait years? Practice, practice, practice! The more the better. And besides, the OP's example it's not even that complicated. It's a simple template with `enable_if` SFINAE.

Comment: @cigien Try this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/EtUDl1SjyXqVvja6 to reproduce the error.

Comment: I fixed my problem; After reading why templates can't be used in source files everything is more clear. Thank you guys so much for the help.

Comment: @Bob__ oh, i see, so @ alanbirtles suggestion was the problem.

Comment: @cigien That's one, but see @ bolov's comment too: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5MlgTAd0rENpD3XX

Comment: @Bob__ Hmm, that doesn't seem to be the error the OP is getting though.

Comment: @bolov Feel free to disagree. But IMHO templates (beyond the very basic) get complicated and difficult *fast*. And even experienced professionals struggle with them. So that's why I say to expect some months/years/time-in-general to get them under your skin. *Most* programmers are not geniuses, and learning C++ templates takes time.

Comment: @cigien Well, it's a different compiler: *"error: template parameter redefines default argument"* (both [1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EtUDl1SjyXqVvja6) and [2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u5F9yT5fpWkF2yQI)) vs. *"redefinition of the default parameter. Parameter 3."*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, they become complicated. But they can be fun and challenging and rewarding. Just because something is complicated doesn't mean you need to stay away from it.

Comment: @bolov I never said "stay away from it". What I tried to say was simply "prepare to have to invest some time (possibly quite a lot) in this".